# JComboBox issue as inner local variable in a ItemListener

Tags: java, variables

I seem to have an issue which I can't get around, and it might be a very simple thing actually. I'll debrief below.

I have a database of all Countries, States and Cities in the world; which is required input in different instances for a GUI I have created. So I did a separate class to call upon every time I need it, here it is:

```
public class countryStateCitySelector {

    private DBHandler DB = new DBHandler();//This is in charge of accesing the Database and I have a set of classes to help me with different consultations. 

    public JComboBox<String> countrySelector() {

        JComboBox<String> cBCountry = new JComboBox<String>();

        List<String> countryNames=DB.classForQuery("SQL Query");//Get country names
        for (int i =0;i<countryNames.size();i++) {
            cBCountry.addItem(countryNames.get(i).toString());
        }
        cBCountry.setSelectedIndex(-1);

        return cBCountry;
    }

    public JComboBox<String> stateSelector(String selectedCountry) {//Get states names

        JComboBox<String> cBState= new JComboBox<String>();

        List<String> idC = DB.classForQuery("SQL Query"); //Get country ID, as is needed for the stateNames SQL query
        String cID=idC.get(0).toString();
        List <String> stateNames = DB.classForQuery("SQL Query");//Get state names
        for (int i=0;i<stateNames.size();i++) {
            cBState.addItem(stateNames.get(i).toString());
        }

        return cBState;
    }
 //And same class for citySelector.
}
```

Here is my main class and the one that creates part of the user's interface, it all works fine in the following part, but I'm sharing to give a better context.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        new screenCreateClients();
    }

    public screenCreateClients() {
        //Creates ContentPane, Windows size, etc..
        createClientBasicDetails();
    }

    public void createClientBasicDetails () {

        //All the GUI for createClientBasicDetails()

        //ComboBoxes
         JComboBox<String> cBCountry = new JComboBox<String>();
         JComboBox<String> cBState = new JComboBox<String>();
         JComboBox<String> cBCity = new JComboBox<String>();

        countryStateCitySelector selPhyAdr = new countryStateCitySelector();
        cBCountry=selPhyAdr.countrySelector();
```

But here is where the problem starts and it is with the *JComboBox cBState = new JComboBox()* variable when I call it within the listener of *cBCountry*, I get the following error: "Local variable cBState defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

```
        cBCountry.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    cBState=selPhyAdr.stateSelector(cBCountry.getSelectedItem().toString());
                } else if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    cBState.removeAll();
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

One of the things that I find weird is that I get the error inside the *if* statement, but I do not get it inside the *else if* statement. I cannot declare the variable as *final*, as it changes every time the country refreshes, and I cannot declare it inside the listener, as it won't be added to the GUI. I would very much appreciate your input here.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your combo boxes should be defined as `instance` variable in your class, not `local` variables.

Comment: Thank you @camickr,  I am a little confused though, is that not how they are defined in the class, as instance variables?

Comment: No, they are defined in the `createClientBasicDetails()` method. Read you text box or search the web for the difference between the two types of variables.